# Thowing an error in `await [].reduce(async ...)` crashes node

Tags: javascript

I noticed today that if I throw an error inside of an await/async reduce, it will crash nodejs.

For example, this will crash my code:

```
    const tests = await [1, 2, 3].reduce(async i => {
        throw new Error("test error");
    }, Promise.resolve([] as any[]));
```

but the code code below is fine:

```
    const tests = [1, 2, 3].reduce(i => {
        throw new Error("test error");
    }, []);
```

or

```
    const tests = await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(async i => {
        throw new Error("test error");
    }));
```

Adding try/catch inside the reduce works well but sometimes I want `reduce` to stop processing and return the error like `await Promise.all([].map(...` does.

```
    const tests = await [1, 2, 3].reduce(async i => {
        try {
            throw new Error("test error");
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, Promise.resolve([] as any[]));
```

I would like `reduce` to behave the same way `map` does when an error is thrown inside of it.

Is there a workaround for this?  An external `reduce` library?

Comment: Your reducer ignores both the promise chain so far _and_ the new value... You're creating multiple unhandled rejections.

Comment: "*sometimes I want reduce to stop processing and return the error*" then you probably don't want `reduce`

Comment: Need more context on why you have a throw inside a reduce in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't crash if you await the accumulator first.

This works as expected.

```
  const tests = await [1, 2, 3].reduce(async (acc, i) => {
        const result = await acc;
        throw new Error("test error"); // <--- error after await acc
        return result;
    }, Promise.resolve([] as any[]));
```

This crashes nodejs

```
  const tests = await [1, 2, 3].reduce(async (acc, i) => {
        throw new Error("test error"); // <--- error before await acc
        const result = await acc;
        return result;
    }, Promise.resolve([] as any[]));
```

I hope this helps someone.